# java.nio.file.FileSystemException:storage/emulated/0/Download/..... :Operation not permitted in Android Studio while copying file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-copying

**Expection while copying file (image or video) in Android Studio**
*java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyStorySaver/Whatsapp/abc.jpg: Operation not permitted*

**Code MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;
    File STATUS_DIRECTORY;
    public static File RootDirectoryWhatsapp = new
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
            File.separator
            +"/Download/MyStorySaver/Whatsapp/");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         STATUS_DIRECTORY = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/abc.jpg");
        checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);


    }


    // Function to check and request permission.
    public void checkPermission(String permission,String permission2, int requestCode)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            // Requesting the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] { permission,permission2 }, requestCode);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                 org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(STATUS_DIRECTORY,RootDirectoryWhatsapp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
                permissions,
                grantResults);


        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

*NOTE: I am using these libraries for permission and copying files*

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
```

*Path*

copying From=  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+
"/WhatsApp/Media/.statuses";

copying_To=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/MyStorySaver/Whatsapp"

Comment: Which Android version in used device? Please out values of used path variables in your code as otherwise we have to guess. Further it is unclear if mentioned path is for source or destination.

Comment: copying From=  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+
                "/WhatsApp/Media/.statuses";

copying_To=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/MyStorySaver/Whatsapp"

Comment: I have attached image where you can check path details

Comment: Dont post code in images. Post only text. You should know that.

Comment: I just post it for clarification. Please guide me, I am really struggling with it

Comment: Remove that image and post complete code. Do not post paths at end but start with them in your code. Assign them to used variables. Make your code readable.

Comment: For instance: `statusModel.getPath();` Nobody will know which path that would be. So better hardcode.

Comment: @blackapps ok sure .

Comment: I have updated code , Please check it now

Comment: Your status directory is a jpg file??

Comment: Please remove all that asking for permission stuff. Its irrelevant. Then post your copy code as there is not any now. Remove the imports too as they are irrelevant.

Comment: @blackapps sir, actually that is the path of that file, which I want to copy.

Comment: I just want to copy a single file ,  name abc.jpg

Comment: Why are you naming a jpg file STATUS_DIRECTORY?

Comment: Does the target directory exist (where you want to copy the file in)?

Comment: yes, target directory exist